# curry in scheme

Tags: scheme, currying

I have this `curry` function:

```
(define curry
(lambda (f) (lambda (a) (lambda (b) (f a b)))))
```

I think it's like `(define curry (f a b))`.

my assignment is to write a function `consElem2All` using `curry`，which should work like

```
(((consElem2All cons) 'b) '((1) (2 3) (4)))
>((b 1) (b 2 3) (b 4))
```

I have wrote this function in a regular way:

```
(define (consElem2All0 x lst) 
  (map (lambda (elem) (cons x elem)) lst))
```

but still don't know how to transform it with `curry`. Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

bearzk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should begin by reading about currying. If you don't understand what curry is about, it may be really hard to use it... In your case, http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jeffm/Papers/curry.html may be a good start.

One very common and interesting use of currying is with functions like reduce or map (for themselves or their arguments).

## Let's define two currying operators!

```scm
(define curry2 (lambda (f) (lambda (arg1) (lambda (arg2) (f arg1 arg2)))))
(define curry3 (lambda (f) (lambda (arg1) (lambda (arg2) (lambda (arg3) (f arg1 arg2 arg3))))))
```

Then a few curried mathematical functions:

```scm
(define mult (curry2 *))
(define double (mult 2))

(define add (curry2 +))
(define increment (add 1))
(define decrement (add -1))
```

And then come the curried reduce/map:

```scm
(define creduce (curry3 reduce))
(define cmap (curry2 map))
```

## Using them

First reduce use cases:

```scm
(define sum ((creduce +) 0))
(sum '(1 2 3 4)) ; => 10

(define product (creduce * 1))
(product '(1 2 3 4)) ; => 24
```

And then map use cases:

```scm
(define doubles (cmap double))
(doubles '(1 2 3 4)) ; => (2 4 6 8)

(define bump (cmap increment))
(bump '(1 2 3 4)) ; => (2 3 4 5)
```

I hope that helps you grasp the usefulness of currying...

Comment: Nitpicks: Your add definition is missing its closing parenthesis and your (creduce + 0) calls should be ((creduce +) 0) as creduce expects one argument.

Comment: I usually forbid myself to post code I didn't copy/pasted from a successful running code. Nice catch!

Comment: @Nowhereman Hi, the link given in your answer seems to be down. Could you point out to another resource for learning currying?

Comment: @dannny It is stil reachable in the WayBack Machine, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20140330131408/http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~jeffm/Papers/curry.html

Answer (score 1):

So your version of curry takes a function with two args, let's say:

```
(define (cons a b) ...)
```

and turns that into something you can call like this:

```
(define my-cons (curry cons))
((my-cons 'a) '(b c)) ; => (cons 'a '(b c)) => '(a b c)
```

You actually have a function that takes three args. If you had a `curry3` that managed 3-ary functions, you could do something like:

```
(define (consElem2All0 the-conser x lst) ...)
```

(like you did, but allowing cons-like functions other than cons to be used!)

and then do this:

```
(define consElem2All (curry3 consElem2All0))
```

You don't have such a `curry3` at hand. So you can either build one, or work around it by "manually" currying the extra variable yourself. Working around it looks something like:

```
(define (consElem2All0 the-conser)
  (lambda (x lst) ...something using the-conser...))
(define (consElem2All the-conser)
  (curry (consElem2All0 the-conser)))
```

Note that there's one other possible use of curry in the map expression itself, implied by you wrapping a lambda around cons to take the element to pass to cons. How could you curry `x` into `cons` so that you get a one-argument function that can be used directly to map?...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps better use a generalized version:

```
(define (my-curry f)
  (lambda args
    (cond ((= (length args) 1)
             (lambda lst (apply f (cons (car args) lst))))
          ((>= (length args) 2)
             (apply f (cons (car args) (cdr args)))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(define (consElem2All0 x lst) 
  (map ((curry cons) x) lst))
```