# In Haskell, (+) is a function, ((+) 2) is a function, ((+) 2 3) is 5. What exactly is going on there?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, programming-languages, partial-application

1. How is this possible, what is going on there?
2. Is there a name for this?
3. What other languages have this same behavior?
4. Any without the strong typing system?

Comment: Get a standard textbook/tutorial for Haskell?

Comment: The names you are looking for are currying and partial application.

Comment: You may achieve something similar in Python if I'm not mistaken, though it's not really the same.

Comment: Can some of the downvoters/vote-to-closers explain what's going on here? To me, this question, though at a beginner level, looks well-formed, precise, and prone to objective answers from Haskell experts -- perfect StackOverflow material.

Comment: Daniel Wagner, thank you very much. As a questioner, it's very hard to antecipate wheter a question will be downvoted like that.

Comment: `+` isn't a function, it's a binary operator.  Any Haskell operator (except unary `-`) can be turned into a function of two variables by placing it in parens: `(+)`.  You can also fill in one of the arguments on either side, like `(+ 2)`. This makes a function of one variable, called an "operator section".

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This behaviour is really simple and intuitive if you look at the types. To avoid the complications of infix operators like `+`, I'm going to use the function `plus` instead. I'm also going to specialise `plus` to work only on `Int`, to reduce the typeclass line noise.

Say we have a function `plus`, of type `Int -> Int -> Int`. One way to read that is "a function of two `Int`s that returns an `Int`". But that notation is a little clumsy for that reading, isn't it? The return type isn't singled out specially anywhere. Why would we write function type signatures this way? Because the `->` is right associative, an equivalent type would be `Int -> (Int -> Int)`. This looks much more like it's saying "a function from an `Int` to (a function from an `Int` to an `Int`)". But those two types are in fact exactly the same, and the latter interpretation is the key to understanding how this behaviour works.

Haskell views all functions as being from a single argument to a single result. There may be computations you have in mind where the result of the computation depends on two or more inputs (such as `plus`). Haskell says that the *function* `plus` is a function that takes a single input, and produces an output which is *another function*. This second function takes a single input and produces an output which is a number. Because the second function was computed by first (and will be different for different inputs to the first function), the "final" output can depend on both the inputs, so we can implement *computations* with multiple inputs with these functions that take only single inputs.

I promised this would be really easy to understand if you looked at the types. Here's some example expressions with their types explicitly annotated:

```
plus       :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus 2     ::        Int -> Int
plus 2 3   ::               Int
```

If something is a function and you apply it to an argument, to get the type of the result of that application all you need to do is remove everything up to the first arrow from the function's type. If that leaves a type that has more arrows, then you still have a function! As you add arguments the right of an expression, you remove parameter types from the left of its type. The type makes it immediately clear what the type of all the intermediate results are, and why `plus 2` is a function which can be further applied (its type has an arrow) and `plus 2 3` is not (its type doesn't have an arrow).

"Currying" is the process of turning a function of two arguments into a function of one argument that returns a function of another argument that returns whatever the original function returned. It's also used to refer to the property of languages like Haskell that automatically have all functions work this way; people will say that Haskell "is a curried language" or "has currying", or "has curried functions".

Note that this works particularly elegantly because Haskell's syntax for function application is simple token adjacency. You are free to read `plus 2 3` as the application of `plus` to 2 arguments, or the application of `plus` to `2` and then the application of the result to `3`; you can mentally model it whichever way most fits what you're doing at the time.

In languages with C-like function application by parenthesised argument list, this breaks down a bit. `plus(2, 3)` is very different from `plus(2)(3)`, and in languages with this syntax the two versions of `plus` involved would probably have different types. So languages with that kind of syntax tend not to have all functions be curried all the time, or even to have automatic currying of any function you like. But such languages have historically also tended not to have functions as first class values, which makes the lack of currying a moot point.

Comment: Good explanation, though of course your example of `plus(2, 3)` vs `plus(2)(3)` and their having different types applies to Haskell too, not just "languages with C-like function application". `plus :: (Int, Int) -> Int` allows `plus(2, 3)` and `plus :: Int -> Int -> Int` allows `plus(2)(3)`

Comment: @Bertie Well yes, although neither of those is an idiomatic way to write the application in Haskell. And `plus (2, 3)` in Haskell is applying a function to a single argument which is a tuple; that comes out in C-like syntax as `plus((2, 3))`. You can of course view functions taking a tuple as encoding of multi-argument functions (just as functions returning functions is an encoding of multi argument functions), but I prefer to think of them separately.

Answer (score 9):

In Haskell, **all functions take exactly 1 input, and produce exactly 1 output**. Sometimes, the input to or output of a function can be another function. The input to or output of a function can also be a tuple. You can simulate a function with multiple inputs in one of two ways:

- Use a tuple as input
  `(in1, in2) -> out`
- Use a function as output*
  `in1 -> (in2 -> out)`

Likewise, you can simulate a function with multiple outputs in one of two ways:

- Use a tuple as output*
  `in -> (out1, out2)`
- Use a function as a "second input" (a la function-as-output)
  `in -> ((out1 -> (out2 -> a)) -> a)`

*this way is typically favored by Haskellers

The `(+)` function simulates taking 2 inputs in the typical Haskell way of producing a function as output. (Specializing to `Int` for ease of communication:)
`(+) :: Int -> (Int -> Int)`

For the sake of convenience, `->` is right-associative, so the type signature for `(+)` can also be written
`(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`

---

`(+)` is a function that takes in a number, and produces another function from number to number.

`(+) 5` is the result of applying `(+)` to the argument `5`, therefore, it is a function from number to number.

`(5 +)` is another way to write `(+) 5`

`2 + 3` is another way of writing `(+) 2 3`. Function application is left-associative, so this is another way of writing `(((+) 2) 3)`. In other words: Apply the function `(+)` to the input `2`. The result will be a function. Take *that* function, and apply it to the input `3`. The result of *that* is a number.

Therefore, `(+)` is a function, `(5 +)` is a function, and `(+) 2 3` is a number.

Answer (score 6):

In Haskell, you can take a function of two arguments, apply it to one argument, and get a function of one argument.  In fact, strictly speaking, + isn't a function of two arguments, it's a function of one argument that returns a function of one argument.

Answer (score 2):

1. In layman's terms, the `+` is the actual function and it is waiting to receive **a certain number of parameters** (in this case 2 or more) until it returns.  If you don't give it two or more parameters, then it will remain a function waiting for another parameter.
2. It's called [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)
3. Lots of functional languages (Scala,Scheme, etc.)
4. Most functional languages are *strongly typed*, but this is good in the end because it reduces errors, which works well in enterprise or critical systems.

As a side note, the language Haskell is named after Haskell Curry, who re-discovered the phenomenon of Functional Currying while working on combinatory logic.

Answer (score 0):

Languages like Haskell or OCaml have a syntax that lends itself particularily to currying, but you can do it in other languages with dynamic typing, like [currying in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697201/400277).